# Not able to Update file stream through Microsoft graph SDK when file is open in Browser

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to Update the excel online file through Microsoft graph SDK, which is in Onedrive, by getting its stream. The update to excel happens correctly when the file is closed. But same Whenever the file is open, I am not able to access the file stream.

```
public async Task<Stream> DownloadSelectedItem(string id) {
    return await graphClient
        .Drive
        .Items[id]
        .Content
        .Request()
        .GetAsync();
}


public async Task<DriveItem> UploadFileToFolder(string targetFolderId, string filename, Stream stream)
    {
        DriveItem uploadedItem;

        uploadedItem = await graphClient.Drive.Items[targetFolderId].ItemWithPath(filename).Content.Request()
                        .PutAsync<DriveItem>(stream);

        return uploadedItem;
    }
```

Is there any way that we can get the stream of the file when its open?

Below is the error received when I try to update the existing file in OneDrive when the file is open

```
Code: accessDenied
Message: Lock token does not match existing lock
Inner error
```

Comment: What are you getting for an error?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur : This the error which i receive {"Code: accessDenied\r\nMessage: Lock token does not match existing lock\r\n\r\nInner error\r\n"}

Comment: How large are the files you downloading? While tiny files can be quickly grabbed, larger files require special handling to download them in chunks.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur: I am able to download the stream of the file but not able to update when the same file is Open in browser.

Comment: I don't follow. Your code sample is downloading a file, not uploading.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur:  What I am trying to do is I am downloading the excel file as a stream, updating the excel stream with closed.XML and updating the existing file stream when the excel file is open in a browser. The same gets updated when the file is not open anywhere. The issue is only when the file is open and the file is getting locked and not letting the code to update it.

Comment: Excel will lock the file and only accept co-authoring capable clients (i.e. Excel 2016, Excel Online, etc.). Since an upload from OneDrive isn't such a client, it won't allow you to perform a write while the file is open. This likely has nothing to do with the stream, it wouldn't allow you to upload the file from a local drive either.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur: Is there any workaround for this issue? I was able to do the same (update excel when a file is open in browser) in Box and also Dropbox

Comment: No. When a file is locked, it cannot be updated/changed. Doing so would cause all sorts of issues for clients currently editing/viewing the document. No to mention that Office Online auto-saves back to storage so your changes would most likely just get overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

It is mean that file you try to edit is open in some browser.You should close it before it is only way